# I use a LoRa-SX1278 on attiny44 (A) and my SPI connection is unstable. Sometimes the node sends the frames, and other times it doesn't

Tags: c++, arduino, lora, lorawan

I used different new components and it did not change anything.
I also added a 16 Mhz crystal to have a more precise clock. it made things a little better.
Maybe it's a question of power? The lora is maybe too greedy for my assembly?

Or Maybe my code is wrong? :

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <LoRa.h>
 
void blink(int nb, int PIN = PA0){
  for(int i = 0; i < nb; i++){
    PORTA |= _BV(PIN);
    delay(500);
    PORTA &= ~_BV(PIN);
    delay(500);
  } 
  delay(5000);
}
 
#define BLINK(X) blink(X)
 
void setup() {
 
  //BLINK(10);
  DDRA |= _BV(PA0);
 
  while(!LoRa.begin(433E6)){
    digitalWrite(PB2, LOW);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(PB2, HIGH);
    delay(500);
    BLINK(1);
    }
  BLINK(2);
  LoRa.setSpreadingFactor(12);
  LoRa.setSignalBandwidth(62.5E3);
  LoRa.setCodingRate4(8);
 
  //while(!LoRa.pairing());
    //Serial.println("Pairing successful/ networkID = " + (String) LoRa.networkId);
 
}
int i = 0;
void loop() {
 
  LoRa.beginPacket();
  LoRa.print("A");
  LoRa.endPacket();
  //BLINK(3);
  //delay(100);
}
```

Comment: Is it LoRa or LoRaWAN, there is a big impacting difference. And did you initialize your SPI bus?

Comment: Thank you. I found the solution. these are the initialization parameters of the attiny which change the behavior of the pins of this one. I'll put the details here when I have time.

Answer (score 1):

Solved! I probed the pins with an ossilo, then I burned the ATtiny initialization sequence in Counter ClockWise using the arduino IDE to match the pins with the desired constants.